# Facebook connect function Logout with android sdk

Tags: android, facebook

My code is as below:

```
public void logoutFromFacebook() {
    mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);

            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    // make Login button visible
                    btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // making all remaining buttons invisible
                    btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnShowAccessTokens.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnFbLogout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
    Object state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
    Object state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
    }
});
}
```

But it does not work and show's an error `validating access Token`. Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I cant but it show error code :101 , error messagee "invalid application Id"

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the error message says "invalid application id" is because you are either not providing an app id or you are providing an invalid app id.

You have to make sure you instantiate `Facebook` in the beginning of your code in the following manner

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(YOUR_APP_ID_HERE);
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
```

Comment: I have add that , but now show error , error validating access token , how this solutinon??